# Can not get ViewRenderer instance from ServiceLocator in Console Request

Tags: php, zend-framework2, sendmail

I'm trying to create a function to send e-mail via consoleRequest. Setup by crontab. I got this error

```
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: 
Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for ViewRenderer
```

when i run from console.

```
$renderer = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ViewRenderer');
$content = $renderer->render ( 'admin/email/tmpl/jobinfo', array (
            "jobs" => $recruitingData 
    ) );
```

Every thing run when i run from web browser. But i got error when i run from console.
Thanks.

Comment: are you doing this within a Controller that extends AbstractActionController or are you within a mail service or amodule.php?

Comment: i do that in Controller that extends AbstractActionController. I can run it in web browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add a php renderer to your console action since your not displaying html content but using the cli which by default cant do this.

```
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer;
....

$renderer = new PhpRenderer();
```

Now add the view you want to render.

```
$template = 'path/to/template/';
$model = new ViewModel();
$model->setTemplate($template);
```

At the end of it all just store the result of the renderer and pass it to your mail function/service/whatever.

```
$yourMailService->whateverMethodYouUseToSetContent($renderer->render($model));
```

Comment: I think this answer is not useful since you are not giving a solution to inject the Renderer. It's an anti pattern.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to send emails via console and getting the following error:

```
======================================================================
The application has thrown an exception!
======================================================================
Zend\View\Exception\RuntimeException
Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "email/welcome.phtml"; resolver could not resolve to a file
```

This because I was setting as template a **.phtml** file inside *module/MyModuleName/view/email* and the PhpRenderer doesn't know this path.

To solve this error is need to register a new resolver and set it's path.

```
use Zend\View\Resolver\TemplatePathStack;

...

// defining the resolver
$resolver = new TemplatePathStack();
$resolver->addPath('full/path/to/view/in/module');

// create a PhpRenderer
$renderer = new PhpRenderer();

// Set the resolver to renderer
$renderer->setResolver($resolver);

// create the ViewModel
$model = new ViewModel();

// And set the template to use
$model->setTemplate('some-template.phtml');

// Finally use it (get example from cptnk in previous answer)
$yourMailService->whateverMethodYouUseToSetContent($renderer->render($model));
```